# Bloquear código fonte HTML

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Boa tarde pessoal!
Já dei uma boa pesquisada, mas nada me resolveu, existe alguma forma de bloquear meu Código Fonte no Source ou deixar ele confuso, para futuras cópias(site feito em html5).
orbigado!

Comment: o html deve obrigatoriamente chegar ao navegador para ele mostrar, então não há como bloquear isso, senão a página não aparece. algumas coisas como imagens podem ser transformadas em bytes por exemplo, mimificar o código, mas nada que previna do código chegar ao navegador. Mantenha o que não quer que seja visto pelo usuário no lado servidor

Comment: Primeiramente que tipo de código vc quer esconder? E se vc quer esconder, como o browser pode garantir a segurança do usuário? Se estiver escondido como vc acha que o Google vai indexar? Reflita

Answer (score 3):

Então vitor, geralmente não é utilizado um obfuscador de marcação html, mas da uma procurada no google em: obfuscate html.

Entrei em um site que dado o html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Joostrap</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

ele gerou um retorno de:

```
<script language="javascript">
<!--
// == Begin Free HTML Source Code Obfuscation Protection from http://snapbuilder.com == //
document.write(unescape('%3C%21%44%4F%43%54%59%50%45%20%68%74%6D%6C%3E%0A%3C%68%74%6D%6C%20%6C%61%6E%67%3D%22%65%6E%22%3E%0A%3C%68%65%61%64%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%63%68%61%72%73%65%74%3D%22%55%54%46%2D%38%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%6E%61%6D%65%3D%22%76%69%65%77%70%6F%72%74%22%20%63%6F%6E%74%65%6E%74%3D%22%77%69%64%74%68%3D%64%65%76%69%63%65%2D%77%69%64%74%68%2C%20%69%6E%69%74%69%61%6C%2D%73%63%61%6C%65%3D%31%2E%30%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%6D%65%74%61%20%68%74%74%70%2D%65%71%75%69%76%3D%22%58%2D%55%41%2D%43%6F%6D%70%61%74%69%62%6C%65%22%20%63%6F%6E%74%65%6E%74%3D%22%69%65%3D%65%64%67%65%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%74%69%74%6C%65%3E%4A%6F%6F%73%74%72%61%70%3C%2F%74%69%74%6C%65%3E%0A%3C%2F%68%65%61%64%3E%0A%3C%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%73%63%72%69%70%74%20%73%72%63%3D%22%64%69%73%74%2F%62%75%6E%64%6C%65%2E%6A%73%22%3E%3C%2F%73%63%72%69%70%74%3E%0A%3C%2F%62%6F%64%79%3E%0A%3C%2F%68%74%6D%6C%3E'));
//-->
</script>
```

porém isso afeta a performance de um jeito ruim.

Você pode procurar também por minificadores de html, caso conheça node tem essa lib que minifica seu html:

[npm da lib html-minifier-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier-loader)

Comment: Muito boa resposta.